# Angular Material custom context menu (right-click)

Tags: angular, angular-material, contextmenu

Using Angular Material, is it possible to override the default context menu (right-click) with my own MatMenu, on a specified template element?

There is the [MatMenuTrigger](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenuTrigger) directive, but it only supports the left-click trigger. Moreover, it only shows the MatMenu in a fixed position relative to the element, and not to the mouse position at the moment of trigger.

I've tried [CdkMenu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview), but I can't get it to work with MatMenu.

Comment: There is the `cdkContextMenuTriggerFor` directive which is made specifically for that, even with an [example](https://material.angular.io/cdk/menu/examples#cdk-menu-nested-context) in the official docs. What is it that you can't get to work? Provide the code and preferably a stackblitz repro of your issue.

Comment: @TotallyNewb the problem with `CdkMenu` is that it seems to be meant only for triggering an `ng-template` - a menu with custom styles (not what I want). I tried to throw a `MatMenu` into the `cdkContextMenuTriggerFor`, but it only accepts a `TemplateRef` as input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open your own **context menu** using below code.

In your **component.html** file you need to put this code

```
<div (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)"></div>
```

You can put below code in end of the html file

```
<!-- an hidden div is created to set the position of appearance of the menu-->
<div style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed;" [style.left]="menuTopLeftPosition.x"
    [style.top]="menuTopLeftPosition.y" [matMenuTriggerFor]="rightMenu"></div>

<!-- standard material menu -->
<mat-menu #rightMenu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-item="item" *transloco="let t">
        <button mat-menu-item>Option 1</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Option 2</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Option 3</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Option 4</button>
    </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

In your **component.ts** file

```
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger, { static: true }) matMenuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger;

menuTopLeftPosition = { x: '0', y: '0' }

onRightClick(event) {
      // preventDefault avoids to show the visualization of the right-click menu of the browser 
      event.preventDefault();

      // we record the mouse position in our object 
      this.menuTopLeftPosition.x = event.clientX + 'px';
      this.menuTopLeftPosition.y = event.clientY + 'px';
      // we open the menu 
      this.matMenuTrigger.openMenu();
}
```